# SELECT DISTINCT from a table with conditions and order from another table

Tags: mysql

I have this table called `table_a`:

```
|id |family   |gender   |stock
 1   bag       man       20
 2   bag       woman     23
 3   clothing  child     4
 4   shoe      man       0
 5   shoe      child     3
 6   bag       unissex   34
 7   bag       child     0
```

And another table called `table_b`:

```
|id |gender
 1   man
 2   woman
 3   child
 4   unissex
```

How could I code correctly the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT gender FROM table_a WHERE family = 'bag' AND stock > '0' ORDER BY table_b.id ASC
```

so that the result would be: `['man','woman','unissex']`. Independently of what the result would be I would like that the resulting array always would have the same order, 'man' in first place, 'woman' in second and so on, and if 'man' is not a result then 'woman' comes to first and so on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your current structure you need to join the tables:

```
SELECT table_a.gender 
FROM table_a JOIN table_b ON table_a.gender=table_b.gender
WHERE table_a.family = 'bag' AND table_a.stock > 0 
GROUP BY table_a.gender
ORDER BY table_b.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Specify the order using **ORDER BY FIELD**

```
SELECT DISTINCT gender FROM table_a 
WHERE family = 'bag' AND stock > '0' 
 ORDER BY FIELD(gender,'man','woman','child', 'unissex')
```

It will work for MySQL